# NGINX Allow access to static assets and index.php

Tags: nginx, access-control-list

We've got an old code base which dumps everything in the public document root, so are wanting to whitelist what files can be accessed.

This is effectively our current config

```
server {
    root /home/forge/www.our-website.com/;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

We have an `index.php` which all dynamic content routes through.

We also have a directory called `assets` which contains static css/images/js etc. inside the document root.

---

How can we allow access to only the index.php file and the contents of the assets directory?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
server {

root /home/forge/www.our-website.com/;

index index.php;

#Deny access to everything that don't match 
location / { deny all; }

#Allow root directory so requests could be passed to index.php
location = / {allow all;} 

#Allow index.php
location = /index.php { 
    allow all;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

#Allow assets directory
location /assets/ { allow all;}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, will have a look when back to work on monday :)